# Connect services DataConnect and DB2 Warehouse on Cloud (former DashDB)

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb, dataconnect

I am working on the migration of a db2 process, which connects to several remotes servers, exports data into our local db, and then manipulates it (insert computed data, calculated times, etc) I have created some activities in DataConnect to replicate the export data from different datasources and load to local tables. The scripts that handles the data have to be done in DB2 Warechouse on Cloud (ex dashdb)

Currently, this scripts run automatically triggered by the first task (manual) However, having the new processes separated (2 services) it does not allow me to automate it. Furthermore, we have many activities in dataconnect, then it keeps switching between dc and db2...and you have to go from one console to the other.

Does anyone know of a Bluemix service which allow schedule or trigger jobs or events from services? Is there a way to use the API and programmatically do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
Bluemix offers Workload Scheduler. Data Connect allows to schedule activities.

Comment: I tried using that service, but I didn't find a way to set neither dashdb, as one of the sources from where to choose tasks, nor DataConnect. Do you know if the service allows them? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Juan,

A couple of things come to mind for automation here. Do the databases that you are speaking of have IP line of sight to the Warehouse DB ? If so remote tables may be able to help depending on the source database. Once the data is visible you should be able to write a SQL process that manages the process all from Warehouse DB.

The other possibility is external tables as long  as the data is visible on the head node. There are some other choices like s3 storage. I think the concept is if that you can push your data into S3 storage you can pull it into Warehouse DB. I think you should be able to coordinate this all from the Warehouse db side as long as the data is visible through  remote tables and/or external tables.

Comment: Hi! Not sure if I understood correctly what you've suggested. The idea is to automate 2 services in IBM Bluemix. Each has it's own processes, jobs, activities. Either programatically or using another service, I'd like to create some kind of process that triggers thos tasks/jobs/scripts alternating from one service task to the other when necessary. If that is what you were trying to explain, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: All I was saying is that I think it could be done from Warehouse DB side using external and remote tables. Remote (federation) can pull directly from DB2 into Warehouse. Also external tables can refer to data that lives in S3 space as another option. Warehouse db can also schedule the execution of a stored proc using dbms_sched. Also Remote (federation) can run stored procs in DB2 that maybe away to go.

Comment: ok, I think I got it. Thanks for the tip. It could be helpful to one piece of the process. Combining this with the other bluemix service is what concerns me. Not sure if that could be done somehow. Thanks